# c# .Net debugging jquery on localhost

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I am trying to do some local debugging before publishing an app to a test platform. The app is written in C#, .Net 4.6.1 and has some jQuery in it. I am using VS 2017.

The main page is simple, one TextBox with a submit button. The jQuery catches the button click and does a `$.get()` request to `/Home/Search`.  This works, I can put breakpoints in the search method and step through it.  The method is an `ActionResult` that returns JSON, like this:

```
    public ActionResult Search(string term) {
        var jsonResult = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            {"note", new List<string>()},
            {"error", new List<string>()}
        };
        ...
        return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Chrome's Developer Tools' Network tab, I can see the generating request is sent to `?term=foo`. The search method gets it and processes the incoming string. It then does the `return` as above. I get nothing back from the request.

However, if I run the thing on localhost and, in a different browser tab, visit `http://localhost:5784/Home/Search?term=foo`, then I get the JSON result I expect.

Is there special configuration I need to set to allow this to run on localhost successfully? If there are config options to set, will they have to be removed when the code is moved to the development machine?

**Edit**  the js:

```
    $.get({
        url: "/Home/Search",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: "foo"
        }
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("DONE /Home/Search");
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAIL");
    });
```

I have used the url path with and without a trailing "/".

**Edit 2**

Request with `url: "/Home/Search"`

```
GET /?term=foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57884
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:57884/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Result: the html page
```

Request with `url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")'`

```
GET /?term=foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57884
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:57884/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Result: the html page
```

Comment: Is the action being hit in both cases, put a breakpoint and check?

Comment: probably a bug in your JavaScript, post that.

Comment: The action is being hit.  I can set breakpoints in the action.  That's all good.  The issue is that the `return` seems to forget where it needs to go

Comment: Pretty sure, the problem is in your JS code

Comment: try to use: `$.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")',//other stuff}`

Comment: @7Reeds I believe you want `.success(function(response))`.  If you use `.done()` it is basically waiting for the request and all to be completed.  Since in JavaScript Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: @RomanKoliada I just tried your suggestion and there is no difference.

Comment: For the failing attempt, does the browser network tab show it coming back as empty or does it keep waiting for the server?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `$.get` in the wrong way. See the [doc].
(https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/8eh9waw9/2/).

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: "foo"
        }
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("DONE /Home/Search");
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAIL");
    });
```

Or this:

```
       $.get('@Url.Action("Search", "Home")', {term: "foo"})
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("DONE /Home/Search");
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("FAIL");
        });
```

Comment: Using the `'@Url.Action("Search", "Home")'` does not seem to matter.  I have tried it both ways you show with the same result.

Comment: @7Reeds Could you show which requests you have for both cases in the browser?

Comment: see the 2nd edit above.  They look the same to me.  I will be putting this on the dev iis server shortly to see what happens there.

Comment: @7Reeds You might have missed something. Please, see my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/8eh9waw9/2/ - it generates the right request

Comment: Interesting: I have seen your fiddle, thank you.  My code looks remarkably the same as your `get` version.  I have since used firefox's dev tools and see that the real first request to `Search/?term=foo` gets canceled and a new one is generated without the method name.  I think this may be a vs2017 vs browser vs localhost issue.  I should have the app on a dev server soon.  hopefully that will clear this up